# pandas df. to_csv skipping values or giving incorrect values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, amazon-s3

I am trying to move data from a pandas dataframe to txt file with sep='|' and I am having problems as the data is not getting copied correctly.

I am trying **df.to_csv('file.txt', header = True, index = False, sep='|')**

I am calculating the sum of a column in the dataframe and that value does not match with sum of same column once it is copied to text file.
I also notice there is one row in the text file where values are placed incorrectly in the columns. Not sure what is causing the issue.

I am trying to move files from one s3 bucket to another s3 Bucket. In the source bucket the its a csv file, i want to chnage it to txt and place in destination bucket.

Final annual sum is same when i read the data to dataframe and make changes to columns etc. but after I copy it to txt and check the txt file in the s3 bucket the values dont match.

```
bucket = 'my bucket'
file = 'file path'

final_df=pd.DataFrame() 
obj = client.get_object(Bucket= bucket, Key= file)
initial_df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'])
print(initial_df['Final Annual'].sum()

del initial_df['clo: 0']
initial_df = initial_df.rename(columns={"col: 0.1": "GTX"})
initial_df['P Name'] = initial_df['P Name'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', ' ')
final_df=pd.concat([final_df,initial_df],sort=False)
print(initial_df['Final Annual'].sum())


file = 'MY_FILE.txt'
bucketdest = 'dest bucket'
final_df.to_csv(file, header = True, index = False, sep='|')
s3_file = 'folder path'+ file
print(s3_file)
client2.upload_file(file,bucketdest,s3_file)
print('loaded')
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: maybe you are calculating the sum and not properly assigning it to an existing or new column?

Comment: Sharing your code and some data that leads to the unintended behavior would definitely help to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @dubbbdan i am calculating the sum just to check if the data is getting copied correctly to txt

Comment: There must be an error somewhere.  Please provide more details of what you are exporting and how you are checking to see if it worked properly.

Comment: @mlang added the code

Comment: should the second print be `print(final_df['Final Annual'].sum())`

Comment: @dubbbdan oops changed it but the values are same for both sums

Comment: Do you really want to sum or do you want to check  `final_df.size` to see if the concatenation worked?

Comment: @dubbbdan i want to see if the concatination worked, and I am testing with sum , the values in the destination bucket file should match with the values in the source file

Comment: Is the sums match, then it worked.

Comment: @dubbbdan but moving to txt is the issue is guess has the txt file has different values

Comment: Is S3 important to the bug? In other words, if you just read the file and write it to a local file, does the issue still show up?

Comment: one of the columns has a pipe "|" in one field , I was thinking that is causing the issue while converting to text with "|" delimiter ? How can i remove specials characters from a pandas column

Comment: Not sure what to say,   The Colima headers are also delimited by |. Open up a python interpreter and inspect each operation.